# Ropsten network contract method call not executing

Tags: contract-invocation

I have function I'd like to execute onto the ropsten blockchain. I expect my metamask account to update balances however I just get this following output back

```
<Function Method(uint256,bytes32) bound to (3, '0x025c9a993431412e485703ef238e0a8d6252cb29a84b7adc4dd6e25b33467394')>
```

Comment: Could you paste your contract or function code please? That would really help in answering. Thanks.